# Neo4j in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, neo4j, embed

I am setting up Neo4j in Android Studio.
I can download directly four folders under neo4j-mobile-android-master.
But I require these to be jar files. 
How do I integrate these within Android Studio, without using maven or git?.

Comment: What is your goal? Run Neo4j on Android or connecting from Android app to Neo4j server?

Answer (score 0):

Android studio using Gradle as build system. I highly recommend you to use Gradle for dependency management instead of downloading jar files manually.

Here is the answer for you original question: [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)